# No software manager in xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

Sorry for maybe a stupid question. But I am a beginner at using linux. I have installed xubuntu, but can't find software manager, image writter and program for erase of disks. In "usual" ubuntu I have seen this programs after the installation of the system. Is it possible to install these programs through the terminal?

Comment: What is the Xubuntu version? What is "image writter"? What is "program for erase of disks"? You can install all programs from Ubuntu using a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

"program for erasing of disks" would be probably be Gparted (disk partition manager)
See? Isn't much easier to provide an actual answer, instead of answering back with another question?
...
"Software manager", at least here in my Xubuntu that I'm running, you can run it from a terminal using gnome-software (running in terminal will allow you to see if any errors appear... use this method when you can't run an app by clicking it with the mouse on menus)
edit: And yeah, I remember in the past using xubuntu as well and Software Manager having this problem of only working on Live-Session from USB, but it would not work anymore after I installed on disk. It's not the best thing ever, sorry to say. I just opened it here on the Live-Session to test it out, it opens up, but it uses a whole lot of internet bandwidth (much more than sudo apt-get update) and it took almost 5 minutes for it to open, with no input whatsoever to the user. It's clunky and unfinished, to say the least. Nothing quite close to what Manjaro offers in terms of this same application.
...
Now, here comes the annoying part: "image writer"... I assume you're talking about anything that would function similar to Windows' MSPaint or Image Viewer (I don't remember the particular names, been years...) Bad news: there isn't one single Linux application that compares to MSPaint, that does everything it does. You will have to use multiple different apps for each thing. For example, one app to view images, another app to paste screenshot from clipboard, another app to crop said screenshot, yet another app (4th one) to insert Text Overlays on top of said screenshot. It's hassle, not gonna lie.
...
Welcome to Linux, what else can I help? I can't post comments yet, because of the "wonderful" way this website is structured. But I think I can help you here this way. Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

1. In Xubuntu the program for installing software should be listed as just `Software` in the application menu.  `All Applications > Software`
2. If it is not installed follow the steps below to install it along with the disk utilities.
3. The programs for erasing disks are `gparted` and/or `gnome-disk-utility`, if you have the Software tool above you can install them using it otherwise continue to the step below.
4. To install all 3 you can run the following command in Terminal (`Application Menu > Accessories > Terminal Emulator` or `Windows Key+T`and run the following commands:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install gparted gnome-software gnome-disk-utility`

Answer (score 0):

The author (@Maksim5) is right in that at least some versions of Xubuntu (in particular, Xubuntu 20.04) do not have a graphical (GUI) software installer coming with the distribution, and the user has to use the terminal, and apt-get.

I believe this to be a bug since Xubuntu positions itself as a distribution for beginners.

Solution: open the terminal, and install [gnome-software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Software) and/or [synaptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_(software)) package managers:

```
  $  sudo apt-get install gnome-software
  $  sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

After that, create desktop shortcuts ("launchers") for gnome-software and synaptic on your desktop
(with right mouse click on some empty spot on your desktop, and then choosing "Create launcher").

I believe that synaptic is more flexible than gnome-software.